# Is this general argument against immortality valid?

Tags: probability, infinity, immortality

I found the following argument [here](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0902/0902.0187.pdf) (although the paper is about a different topic):

> **A General Argument Against Immortality:**
>
> The method of Theory Confirmation can be applied to the question of immortality.  In general, if we are immortal, there would be two classes of observations: Those made by normal people within a normal lifespan, and those made in the ‘afterlife’.  For ‘quantum immortality’ the ‘afterlife’ will be taken to mean those who find themselves to be much older than a normal human lifespan. If the ‘afterlife’ is infinite, then it will have infinitely more integral measure than the normal life.  Thus, the effective probability of finding oneself in a normal lifetime would
> be zero.  If there is no ‘afterlife’ then the effective probability of that would be unity.  By applying Bayesian reasoning, this implies that if one does find oneself in a normal lifetime, as we do, there must be no infinite afterlife.

Is this argument valid? To me, it seems that it is obviously false, but I may be missing the nuances of the argument. I would object that there is no random sampling here, which the author seems to assume. We are  not randomly sampling the time in which we exist. If this argument is valid, we can make a general argument against the possibility of indefinite time. If time is indefinite, there is a zero probability that time is where it is currently, yet it is.

So, is this argument valid? How does it avoid my objections, especially the seeming conclusion that time cannot be indefinite?

Comment: It seems to you that the *conclusion* is false or that the *argument* is invalid? If it is the latter, why? The "nuances" are listed on the same page, one has to accept MWI (which is still a minority view), even probability zero does not make normal lifespans impossible, and finite "afterlife" does not even produce zero probability.

Comment: @Conifold I think that the argument is invalid, which makes the conclusion invalid (that immortality is extremely unlikely because of the fact that it is infinite in time), because of the reasons I lay out in my question. My question is not about anything related to MWI, I'm just wondering if the general argument that immortality is extremely unlikely stands.

Comment: The author explicitly says, also on the same page, "*This proof still leaves the possibility that the MWI is false and that we would have been immortal if only it had been true.  However, advocates of “quantum immortality” believe the MWI and QI are true*". The probability setup explicitly relies on MWI, hence random sampling isn't needed, and your analogy to the time point does not work. Its probability is 0 regardless of indefinite time, and for intervals you have to assume equidistribution over all points to get 0, which the afterlife argument does not.

Comment: If the argument was valid, you could imho prove, that death or any other future event is impossible as well. Technically it's claiming "the propability of making an observation before any future point T in time is very small compared to making that observation after T". Since we are all currently making that observation before T, it's unlikely that T exists." Which is obviously wrong. Perhaps because it would assume random sampling in time, as you already mentioned...?

Comment: @Conifold Maybe I don't understand his argument then. How does this passage: "If the ‘afterlife’ is infinite, then it will have infinitely more integral measure than the normal life.  Thus, the effective probability of finding oneself in a normal lifetime would be zero.  If there is no ‘afterlife’ then the effective probability of that would be unity.  By applying Bayesian reasoning, this implies that if one does find oneself in a normal lifetime, as we do, there must be no infinite afterlife." rely on MWI? Isn't he constructing an argument based purely on probability and time spans?

Comment: MWI is needed to get an ensemble that makes probability meaningful, if we had a single universe it makes no sense to talk about such probabilities. It also allows to treat different branches as equiprobable on theoretical grounds (your "random sampling"). He does not, however, assume that lifespans are equiprobable, he just needs the survival function to have a non-integrable tail.

Comment: @Conifold I see, thank you. So his argument is not saying anything about immortality in general? He is only talking about "quantum immortality"? If this is the case, why does it make no sense to talk about an infinite time in single universe?

Comment: It does make sense to talk about infinite time in a single universe, but what sense does it make to talk about "probability" of events that exist in a single copy? One would have to explain what the ensemble is and why "we" constitute a random sampling from it.

Comment: @Conifold But since "we" are not in the "afterlife" (as the author uses it), what else would one expect from an ensemble of "us's"? What would be more likely for us to experience if immortality existed, which makes immortality like this doubtful? Also, this argument requires that these multiple worlds are nondeterministic, right? If they are deterministic, then the argument doesn't hold?

Comment: With a single timeline I do not see how to set up an ensemble (unless there are many other societies "like ours" in this single universe), so probabilistic arguments are moot. Just as anthropic principle only works if we assume a whole ensemble of universes, a unique brute fact is what it is regardless of what is "likely" in some contrived abstract sense.

Comment: @Conifold I guess I still don't understand the argument. He says, "In general, if we are immortal, there would be two classes of observations: Those made by normal people within a normal lifespan, and those made in the ‘afterlife’." So the argument is that since we appear in the smaller class, it is unlikely that there are two classes after all? But this only applies if the sampling between the two classes is random... but it isn't. Since we appear in one class (the smaller one) and could not appear in the other class, why does it mean anything that we indeed appear in the smaller class?

Comment: It applies if the lifespans are distributed with a non-integrable tail. Under MWI, we can look at probabilities of whatever abstractly defined classes we want, those classes are always there. Of course, we have to  assume that we are "randomly sampled" to apply the computed probabilities to ourselves, but that is standard and highly likely, again under MWI. There is no real sampling happening here, and hence no issue of it being random. It could still be that "we" are a fluke, MWI simply says that is "metaphysically" unlikely because it generates copious timelines where "we" aren't.

Comment: @Conifold I see, so does this argument apply to considerations of immortality outside of this "quantum immortality"? Many will say that their god gives them immortality of some sort, and some even for other beings within this universe or in another one. They also presumably think that the universe is deterministic. Would this argument apply here?

Comment: It does if one can generate an ensemble like MWI's. Some forms of modal realism, or Vilenkin's inflated universe with prolific causally isolated regions might do it. Conditions are the same as for anthropic reasoning. If one wants to explain that we are as we are because we are likely to be so they better have a world generating machine that makes "likely" matter.

Comment: The question assumes immortality is just like mortality but in another place. The usual notion of immortality is the transcendence of time for the 'Perennial Now', , not an endless period of time. As you say, immortality in time is an incoherent idea.

Comment: @Conifold I see. Can the argument be sidestepped if you declare whatever state the multiverse is in a metaphysical necessity? If we say that we find ourselves in the state we do because it is metaphysically necessary (as in, it could not have been otherwise), the probabilistic argument does not get off the ground, correct (because measuring probabilities of metaphysical necessities is incoherent)?

Comment: @PeterJ I did not intend to say that "immortality in time is an incoherent idea," did I not phrase my question correctly? Since you say that it is, however, why do you think that it is incoherent?

Comment: Whatever we declare has to be plausible and explanatory. What that is depends on context and viewpoint, I am not sure that the claim of "metaphysical necessity" is either (it seems to be invoked *ad hoc*, just to defeat this argument). But to reject a conclusion it is enough to reject a premise (in this case, having an ensemble with certain properties), there is no need to claim anything in particular instead.

Comment: @Conifold That makes sense. But what exactly are the properties this ensemble must have? Must they be "generated" from a purely random distribution?

Comment: Effectively, yes, and the distribution should not be too clustered, which still means a pretty prolific ontology of universes only one of which we can ever have access to.

Comment: @Conifold So the argument fails in a deterministic universe (because there is not a random distribution)? Is there not good debate as to whether or not the universe is deterministic?

Comment: This debate is millenia old (before determinism there was fatalism), and as inconclusive as ever. But it does not work even in the indeterministic universe of the standard (Copenhagen) interpretation of QM. If only one possibility is realized, instead of a whole sample space, "likely" becomes moot.

Comment: @Conifold Thank you for your time. One last question: what does "should not be too clustered" mean? Where exactly is the threshold between clustered and not clustered enough?

Comment: The author's condition is that "afterlife... have infinitely more integral measure than the normal life", i.e. the effective probability of being older than a given age 
does not tend to zero for older ages. Otherwise, "this certainly is not immortality in any meaningful sense".

Comment: @user43277 - It would be because Immortality in time requires that time is fundamental.

Comment: @PeterJ Why must time by fundamental? If we live now "in time", why cannot that simply continue?

Comment: @user43277 - It's a big topic. The idea that time is fundamental is problematic, and 'immortality' as spoken of in religion is rarely a period of time. Usually it is the transcendence of time. .

Comment: @PeterJ Yes, I agree that immortality usually isn't talked about in the context of time. But why does the idea that time is not fundamental problematic for the idea of immortality?

Comment: @user43277 - Time being fundamental is a problem for metaphysics, not just for immortality as a duration. Physicists also have a problem with it. It's big topic but the various arguments would emerge from a google search. .